# Hair particles eliminates all shadows

Tags: particles, hair, shadows

I finished up a scene with a tree, but when I activate the hair particle of some roots, all shadows disappear, is it a bug?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you share your blend file

Comment: have you made sure that the 'monitor' icon or eye icon in front of your light in the outliner is not turned off? can you show?

Comment: You mean the one in the top right? In the first pic there are four point lights, if its that, they are turned on, if not, can you please explain? Im going nuts, lol. Thanx!!